# Can train but can’t interact with new bot

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5, rasa

I am trying to start a new bot following [the tutorial for Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ewIABo0OkU). If I can reach to the point [where the model is trained](https://youtu.be/4ewIABo0OkU?t=188). Contrary to what's happening in the video I can't interect with it:

```
(rasa_env3) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Rasa>rasa init
Welcome to Rasa! 

To get started quickly, an initial project will be created.
If you need some help, check out the documentation at https://rasa.com/docs/rasa.
Now let's start! 

? Please enter a path where the project will be created [default: current directory] .
? Directory 'C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Rasa' is not empty. Continue?  Yes
Created project directory at 'C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Rasa'.
Finished creating project structure.
? Do you want to train an initial model?   Yes
Training an initial model...
Training Core model...
Processed Story Blocks: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 1186.04it/s, # trackers=1]
Processed Story Blocks: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 429.45it/s, # trackers=5]
Processed Story Blocks: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 165.34it/s, # trackers=20]
Processed Story Blocks: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 172.61it/s, # trackers=24]
Processed trackers: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:00<00:00, 419.68it/s, # actions=16]
Processed actions: 16it [00:00, 1265.32it/s, # examples=16]
Processed trackers: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 231/231 [00:02<00:00, 86.55it/s, # actions=126]

(rasa_env3) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Rasa>
```

As you can see I can't talk with the bot. Do you know how I can sort out this issue ?

## Update with rasa shell

```
(rasa_env3) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Rasa>rasa shell
Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.5
        SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
                   HDF5 Version: 1.10.5
```

....
           Strict File Format Checks: OFF
        Optimization Instrumentation:
    Bye...

Comment: To talk to bot run `rasa shell` command.

Comment: @Naktibalda Unfortunately it doesn't return anything but a warning that I'm going to add in my question

Comment: seems like you have 2 versions of HDF5 installed? check `pip list | grep h5py` and `pip list| grep hdf5`. Also, did you manually install HDF5 in any way?